# Security when connecting to EC2 instance

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rds

I have just built a cloud using AWS.

It includes a few servers including an RDS.

The RDS server is running an accounting application.  I have limited access to this server to a certain security group, I've also set up some group policy.

What I wanted to know is, what security can I put in place to protect the server.. i.e. before users even get logged into it?

Maybe something like a dial in VPN, something that users have to authenticate with before they have the option of accessing the RDS server.

Comment: Giving users access to your RDS sounds like a security concern itself. Do they NEED direct access to the DB Server?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this might be a fit for an [Amazon private cloud](http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/). The pricing is the same as for public instances, the thing you pay for is the VPN access on a per connection / per hour basis.

Comment: Hi David, Yes i have build a Private Cloud for this company.  One of the servers we built is a Remote Desktop Server with some accounting software on it.  The server has an Elastic IP assigned to it so it can be accessed by remote users.  I'd like to an an extra layer of security before this, a VPN sounds like what we need.  Can this be set up on a per user basis?